# describing a block diagram // How do I describe multiplying a signal through multiple branches formally?

Tags: filter-design

Let's say I made this block diagram and I want to explain it:

[image]

FYI: $x$ is a signal and each $y$ box is a matrix

***I want to say that:***

The signal $x$ is multiplied by each matrix $y$ in the different branches independently to produce 
$f_0=xy_0$

$f_1=xy_1$

...

$f_m=xy_m$

I want to ask the experts in the signal processing world if this is formal enough? or am I sounding weird?

***Edit 1:***

*What if I said:*

The signal $x$ is multiplied by a set of matrices $y_k$ where $k = 0,1,..., m$

does it sound better? or would it imply that $x$ is multiplied like: $x*y_0*y_1*...*y_k$

which is **NOT** what I intend to say

Comment: If the $y_m$ are matrices already, why are you splitting them into separate paths? Your first statement seems clear enough.

Comment: $x$ is a $1 \times N$ vector and each $y$ is an $N \times N$ matrix @PeterK.

Comment: So why not just have $Y$ as a $N\times N(m+1)$ matrix?

Comment: @PeterK. my head  froze while imagining it this way.

Comment: I find anti-freeze works wonders on neurons. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is:

- Add $m$ multiplier blocks, using a circle with a $\times$ inside
- Each multiplier would have inputs $X$ and $Y_k$
- Each multiplier would have output $f_k$
- Be consistent in the use of bold typeface, uppercase and lowercase

Then I would say something like "The system has input $X$ and outputs $f_k=XY_k$, for $k = 0,\ldots,m$. In the diagram, $\times$ stands for signal-matrix multiplication, which is defined as follows...".